In jsFiddle, how do i access the js pane from the html pane?
In jsFiddle, I need to access a function in my js pane from my html pane.
My jsFiddle url is: https://jsfiddle.net/backspaces/sbfm9gu5/6/
My jsFiddle html pane looks like:
<html>

<head>
  <title>hello</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="module">
    // import runModel from js pane. This is a guess on how to refer to it:
    import runModel from 'https://jsfiddle.net/backspaces/sbfm9gu5/embedded/js'
    const results = await runModel("modelDiv") // default steps, fps 
  </script>
  <div id="modelDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>

The js pane looks like:
import TwoDraw from "https://code.agentscript.org/src/TwoDraw.js";
import Animator from "https://code.agentscript.org/src/Animator.js";

import Model from "https://code.agentscript.org/models/HelloModel.js";

export default async function runModel(div, steps = 500, fps = 30) {
  const model = new Model(); // use model's default world options
  await model.startup();
  model.setup();

  // ==============================

  const drawOptions = {
    turtlesSize: 4
  };

  const view = new TwoDraw(model, {
    div,
    patchSize: 20,
    drawOptions
  });

  // ==============================

  const anim = new Animator(
    () => {
      model.step();
      view.draw();
    },
    steps, // how many steps
    fps // at fps steps/second
  );

  return { model, view, anim };
}

This doesn't work. No error messages but does not show the model running. It runs fine in codepen.
Is the url incorrect:
import runModel from 'https://jsfiddle.net/backspaces/sbfm9gu5/embedded/js'
.. or does jsFiddle not use es6 javascript?
.. or should I try a different approach?
Thanks for any help you can give me!
